# Did Jaime ever mourn Joffrey's death?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The only scene with Jaime and Joffrey's corpse has Jaime raping Cersei instead of mourning his son. Did I miss a scene, or did Jaime simply not care about Joffrey? I'll accept book answers.

Comment: The real question here is: did _anyone_, besides Cersei, care about Joffrey?

Comment: Robert maybe?  .

Comment: Did Jaime mourn anyone's death? He isn't really the mourning type. Except maybe his sword hand.

Comment: @MishaR Well he sure mourned his father but after his own fashion with myriad of emotions like sorrow, guilt, anger and laughter running through his brain. His aunt however seemed to think that Jaime did not care enough for his father while Jaime's offending comments could be forgiven as a honest mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No Jaime did not care for Joffrey. When Joffrey was born, Jaime was expressly forbidden by Cersei to not to show or harbour any affections for Joffrey out of fear that someone might discover their secret.

> Jaime had seen him born, that was true, though more for Cersei than
>   the child. **But he had never held him. "How would it look?" his sister
>   warned him** when the women finally left them. "Bad enough Joff looks
>   like you without you mooning over him." **Jaime yielded with hardly a
>   fight**. The boy had been a squalling pink thing who demanded too much
>   of Cersei's time, Cersei's love, and Cersei's breasts. **Robert was
>   welcome to him**. 
> <sub>A Storm of Swords - Jaime VII</sub>

And When he learnt that Joffrey died, Jaime was concerned only about how Cersei would be feeling and he did not feel distressed himself at all.

> The king is dead, they told him, never knowing that Joffrey was his
>   son as well as his sovereign.
>
> "The Imp opened his throat with a dagger," a costermonger declared at
>   the roadside inn where they spent the night. "He drank his blood from
>   a big gold chalice." The man did not recognize the bearded one-handed
>   knight with the big bat on his shield, no more than any of them, so he
>   said things he might otherwise have swallowed, had he known who was
>   listening.
>
> "The dwarf's wife did the murder with him," swore an archer in Lord
>   Rowan's livery. "Afterward, she vanished from the hall in a puff of
>   brimstone, and a ghostly direwolf was seen prowling the Red Keep,
>   blood dripping from his jaws." Jaime sat silent through it all,
>   letting the words wash over him, a horn of ale forgotten in his one
>   good hand. Joffrey. My blood. My firstborn. My son. He tried to bring
>   the boy's face to mind, but his features kept turning into Cersei's.
>   She will be in mourning, her hair in disarray and her eyes red from
>   crying, her mouth trembling as she tries to speak. She will cry again
>   when she sees me, though she'll fight the tears. His sister seldom
>   wept but when she was with him. She could not stand for others to
>   think her weak. Only to her twin did she show her wounds. She will
>   look to me for comfort and revenge. 
> <sub>A Storm of Swords - Jaime VII</sub>

And then we see that Jaime realises that he simply felt nothing for the child who might have been his seed but was not his son.

> **He was curiously calm. Men were supposed to go mad with grief when
>   their children died, he knew**. They were supposed to tear their hair
>   out by the roots, to curse the gods and swear red vengeance. **So why
>   was it that he felt so little?** The boy lived and died believing Robert
>   Baratheon his sire. [.....]
>
> And now he’s dead. **He pictured Joff lying still and cold with a face
>   black from poison, and still felt nothing. Perhaps he was the monster
>   they claimed. If the Father Above came down to offer him back his son
>   or his hand, Jaime knew which he would choose**. He had a second son,
>   after all, and seed enough for many more. **If Cersei wants another
>   child I’ll give her one... and this time I’ll hold him**, and the Others
>   take those who do not like it. Robert was rotting in his grave, and
>   Jaime was sick of lies. 
> <sub>A Storm of Swords - Jaime VII</sub>

He did not rape Cersei beside Joffrey's bier in the books, He took the initiative but Cersei wanted it as well. There he notes, irritated, to himself how his sister keeps referring to their son as "My Son".

And later he clearly states how he feels about his children.

> “You were Robert’s queen. And yet you won’t be mine.”
>
> “I would, if I dared. But our son—”
>
> “Tommen is no son of mine, no more than Joffrey was.” His voice was
>   hard. “You made them Robert’s too.” 
> <sub>A Feast for Crows - Jaime I</sub>

So in conclusion:

1. Jaime does not seem like the traditional fatherly sort, although that might have been because of his sister's lies and secrets that made Jaime sick. Nevertheless He was only too glad to stop developing any affection for Joff. He did however feel affection for Tommen and Myrcella.
2. Jaime resented the fact that his sister made the children Robert's and hers. While he's irritated whenever she says something along those lines, he certainly doesn't make any effort to remedy that himself.
3. Jaime didn't feel any sorrow at Joffrey's death, he'd practiced apathy towards the boy for far too long. The fact that he'd rather choose a hand than Joffrey's life if he were given a choice says it all.

Answer (score 1):

In the show he may have felt some sorrow, though it wasn't made explicit on-screen. He clearly loved at least one of his children (Myrcella), so it's not beyond him. Joffrey was.. Joffrey though.

When [Olenna Tyrell admits to poisoning Joffrey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Djtf-nyQto) he seems pretty upset, but that could be more about Tyrion getting the blame than the fact that Joffrey died.

Comment: That's a good point but I personally think he's more angry than upset there